# Is 15 million page faults usuall for the process Memory Compression?

Tags: windows-10, memory, compression

I have a windows 10 PC with 8GB of ram, an AMD Ryzen 5 (3.2Ghz) and a GTX 1050 Ti. It will run very smooth when I am not doing things but struggles whenever I try and do a lot of multitasking, despite using less than 30% CPU and 60% memory.

I have checked the page faults for applications and I have over 15 million page faults despite only just turning on my computer.

Page faults for windows process:

[image]

Comment: Windows will start to page at approx 50% RAM usage. You only have 8GB, pretty much min spec these days. Yes, it's going to page a lot. A 'page fault' is not an error, it's a 'natural process', a part of paging to & from disk. CPU usage is irrelevant.

Comment: 15 million page faults is not much : My browser is currently showing 25 million and growing and the computer is running smoothly. Run Resource Monitor, Memory section, column "Hard Faults" sorted in descending order, for process and also total. Soft page faults don't matter. High Hard Faults means lots of swapping.

Comment: Memory Compression is my highest scoring program hovering around 4 - 10 hard faults with MsMpEng.exe next at about 5 faults.